# Different behaviour between 'docker run' and running command from bash within container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq

I am trying to build an image for a RabbitMQ server and I am facing the following problem.
Within the Dockerfile I have the line

> "RUN /rabbitmq_server-3.5.3/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management"

This causes the build process to stall when running this command.
When commenting out that line and later running a container with that image by invoking

> docker run myImage /rabbitmq_server-3.5.3/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

the same behaviour occurs: the container will not stop, and when inspecting the container I see that the command runs forever.

When running the same image by invoking

> docker run -it myImage /bin/bash

and then invoking

> /rabbitmq_server-3.5.3/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

from within the container the command returns and everything works fine.
Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

**Dockerfile:**

```
from privateRegistry:5000/base/rhel7
ADD rpms/ /rpms
RUN rpm -i /rpms/erlang-17.4-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
RUN mv /rpms/rabbitmq_server-3.5.3 /
RUN rm -rf /rpms
RUN /rabbitmq_server-3.5.3/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
EXPOSE 5672
EXPOSE 15672
EXPOSE 25672
```

Docker build stalls on the command to enable the management plugin.

**'run' Command on the image when building the image with the last "RUN" commented out:**

```
docker run -it privateRegistry:5000/base/rabbit /rabbitmq_server-3.5.3/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

Regardless of using -it or sending input on STDIN via '<' does not return and not produce any output.

**Inside the container (started with /bin/bash as command)**

```
/rabbitmq_server-3.5.3/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

interactively within the container, the command produces output and returns.

**UPDATE**

I have pinned the problem further down to the way erl gets called from the rabbitmq-plugins script. The original script calls erl via exec. In this case it hangs forever when being called with 'docker run' or being called from within a Dockerfile. When removing the 'exec' and calling erl directly it works via 'docker run' and from within a Dockerfile. 
This however seems to be specific for erl. I have tried calling other commands via exec from within a script and have not observed similar problems.

Comment: Can you show a reproducer, the Dockerfile, the whole `docker run` command?

Comment: I have edited the question to include sample code. Unfortunately the base image (rhel7) is not available publicly. The rabbitmq server installation is the generic Unix release from the rabbitMQ homepage and the erlang rpm is from the rabbitMQ homepage as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the command is trying to read something on the *stdin*.

Check that and in that case try to redirect the stdin with **<** and the desired input. Like this.

```
/rabbitmq_server-3.5.3/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management <<< y
```

or

```
/rabbitmq_server-3.5.3/sbin/rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management <<< ""
```